# How can I add padding around a div with display:table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a div containing vertically centered text. I need the div to have padding around it and a border, I want it to look just like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlgIY.png

This is the closest I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/cym5jhzL/

```
<div id="table-header-phone">

    <div id="image-container" class="cell-header-image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y3dNk4q.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="tagline-phone" class="cell-phone">
        <div class="tagline">Text can be added here, this needs to stay centered</div>
        <div class="phone-number">(800) 555-5555</div>
    </div>   

</div>

#table-header-phone {
    display: table;
    width: 940px;
    background: navy;
    padding: 20px;
}

#tagline-phone {
    background: #DD1D1D;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell-header-image {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 630px;
    position:relative;
}

.cell-phone {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cym5jhzL/1/

Added:

```
#image-container { display: block; margin-right: 10px; }
```